# Question about the behavior of toString on integers

Tags: java, tostring

Why does an integer alone in returning a String not work, but it does work when adding a String next to it?
Does it suddenly convert the integer like with something as (Integer.toString())?

```
public class Car {
String brand;
String model;
int hp;

@Override
public String toString() {
    return hp; //this doesn't work because it wants to return int.
  //return hp + brand; does work for some reason.
  /*return Integer.toString(hp); could it be doing something like this behind 
  the scenes?*/
}}
```

Comment: Please don't post images of code. It's just text, so post that here properly formatted - see https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the [Java Language Specification](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se17/html/jls-5.html#jls-5.4):

> String contexts apply only to an operand of the binary + operator which is not a String when the other operand is a String.

> The target type in these contexts is always String, and a string conversion (§5.1.11) of the non-String operand always occurs.

Which means that when you do `hp + brand`, since `brand` is a `String` the rule above kicks in, `hp` gets converted to a `String` and concatenation occurs, resulting in a `String`.

Comment: Wow! thank you! That's such a detailed explanation.

Answer (score 0):

This is because of the way Java handles strings. When you try to 'add' anything to a string, it results in a 'concatenate' operation. Here is a good article that explains it https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/addition-and-concatenation-using-plus-operator-in-java/

For example:

```
int n1 = 10;
int n2 = 20;
int n3 = 30;
int n4 = 40;

// Below statement will print the sum 100 as all operands are `int` 
System.out.println(n1 + n2 + n3 + n4); 

// Introducing a string changes the behavior
System.out.println(n1 + "" + n2 + n3 + n4); // Will print 10203040 (concatenated)
```

Also worth noting is that the expressions are evaluated from left-to-right. See below:

```
System.out.println(n1 + n2 + "" + n3 + n4); // Will print 303040
```

Comment: hmm, is it good practice to make use of Integer.toString() if I only want to return the int as a String then? I mean sure I could do something like (hp + "" ) but that might end up just looking unnatural.